# Why can the eigendecomposition of a matrix be written in summation form?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am reading in a textbook that for a symmetric matrix A, we can write

$$
A = P\Lambda P^T = \sum_i \vec{e_i}\vec{e_i}^T\lambda_i
$$

where $\vec{e_i}$ are the eigenvectors of the matrix, $P$ is an orthogonal matrix with $\vec{e_i}$ as the columns, and $\lambda_i$ are the corresponding eigenvalues.

However, I am not seeing why the second equivalence is true, i.e., why that summation is the same as the matrix product $P\Lambda P^T$. I have tried writing out the matrices on a piece of paper and looking at it element-wise but it is a little too convoluted for me to make anything of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider vectors of the standard basis, i.e., a vector $\vec i$ whose entries are one at index $i$ and zeroes elsewhere.
A product $\vec i \ \vec j {}^{\rm T}$ gives you a matrix whose entries are one at location $(i,j)$ and zeroes elsewhere.
Then consider matrix $\Lambda$ (which is diagonal) as a sum of such product matrices (scalated up to eigenvalues):
$$\Lambda =\sum_i \vec i \ \vec i {}^{\rm T} \lambda_i.$$
Then
$$P \Lambda P^{\rm T}
 =P \Big(\sum_i \vec i \ \vec i {}^{\rm T} \lambda_i\Big) P^{\rm T}
 =\sum_i P \vec i \ \vec i {}^{\rm T}  P^{\rm T}\lambda_i
 =\sum_i (P \vec i) (P \vec i) {}^{\rm T} \lambda_i.
$$
A product of the form $P \vec i$ actually gives the $i$th column of $P$, which is $\vec e_i$.

Comment: It is maybe not quite as intuitive as I would like, but I understand it. Thank you!